# Copy + Paste a cell, keeping the cell reference the same but increasing the column increment by one

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm working on a dashboard (Google Sheets) at work, which shows all the figures for 12 different sites. The sites are arranged in rows with columns used for different figures (revenue, bar sales, labour, etc, etc).

This data is pulled from the individual sheet each site has, which has the different figures in rows, and each week as a column.

So currently I'm using:

```
=OFFSET(Central!$AD$98,0,1)
```

This pulls the number figure one to the right of the previous week, which is fine. However when I copy and paste this for the next week it will just pull the same number. Is there anyway of increasing the increment by 1 every time I copy and paste it? So the original cell referenced stays the same, but the first week its 1 across, then 2 across, then 3 across, etc